# can't make a while loop to move from one class to another in c++ using SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

the problem that i face in my code is when the game starts it work fine but when the user want to return to the pricipal menu the application stops

main.cpp----->

```
int main ( int argc, char** argv )
 {
        int x = 5;
        while (1){
        menuPrincipale p;
        x = p.start();
         if (x==2){
            Aide a;
            a.start();
         }
        }
  }
```

menuPrincipale.cpp---->

```
 #include "snake.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

menuPrincipale::menuPrincipale()
{
        SDL_Rect positionFond;
        positionFond.x = 0;
        positionFond.y = 0;
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
        screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 400, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
        SDL_WM_SetCaption("Menu Principale", NULL);
        /* Chargement d'une image Bitmap dans une surface */
        menu = SDL_LoadBMP("snake.bmp");
        /* On blitte par-dessus l'écran */
        SDL_BlitSurface(menu, NULL, screen, &positionFond);
        SDL_Flip(screen);

}


menuPrincipale::~menuPrincipale()
{
        TTF_CloseFont(font);
        TTF_Quit();
        SDL_Quit();
}


int menuPrincipale::start()
{
    SDL_Event event;
    while (1)
{
    SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
    switch(event.type)
    {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            return 0;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
                case SDLK_ESCAPE: // Veut arrêter le jeu
                    return 0;
                    break;

                case SDLK_1: // Demande à jouer
                    SDL_Flip(screen);
                    SDL_FreeSurface(menu); /* On libère la surface */
                    SDL_Quit();
                    return 1;
                    break;

                case SDLK_2: // afficher l'aide
                    SDL_Flip(screen);
                    SDL_FreeSurface(menu); /* On libère la surface */
                    SDL_Quit();
                    return 2;
                    break;

                case SDLK_3: // quitter le jeux
                    return 0;
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }


}
}
```

Aide.cpp------>

```
#include "snake.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

Aide::Aide()
{
        SDL_Rect positionFond;
        positionFond.x = 0;
        positionFond.y = 0;
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
        screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 400, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
        SDL_WM_SetCaption("Help", NULL);
        /* Chargement d'une image Bitmap dans une surface */
        menu = SDL_LoadBMP("aide.bmp");
        /* On blitte par-dessus l'écran */
        SDL_BlitSurface(menu, NULL, screen, &positionFond);
        SDL_Flip(screen);


}


Aide::~Aide()
{
        TTF_CloseFont(font);
        TTF_Quit();
        SDL_Quit();
}

void Aide::start()
{
    SDL_Event event;
    while (1)
{
    SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
    switch(event.type)
    {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
                case SDLK_r: // Demande à jouer
                    SDL_Flip(screen);
                    SDL_FreeSurface(menu); /* On libère la surface */
                    SDL_Quit();
                    break;
            }
    }


}
}
```

when i display the help page (Aide.cpp) and i want to return to the Principal menu (menuPrincipale.cpp) the application stops..

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call the `SDL_Quit()`, `TTF_Quit()` and `TTF_CloseFont(font)` in the destructor of Aide. SDL_Quit() should only be called once, the same with the TTF library.